# I installed a honeywell WiFi thermostat, the primary heat runs the heat pump instead oh the gas furnace

Tags: hvac

I want to run the gas furnace, but the primary heat turns on the heat pump. If I turn up the thermostat several degrees, then the gas furnace comes on . In emergency settings, nothing happens. How do I run the gas furnace and not the heat pump.Ted

Comment: Why do you want to run the gas furnace? What are your outdoor conditions at the moment? What make and model is your heat pump for that matter?

Comment: You may want to think harder about your configuration.  Main heat is the one that's cheapest to run.  Auxiliary heat is the one that may be **a little** more expensive to run, but is perfectly OK to use when you simply want to speed up heating, e.g. 30 minutes before you arrive home.   Emergency heat is the one that is prohibitively expensive to run, but works at all temperatures (heat pumps don't) and should not be run unless everything else has failed.